# JasperReports Server encountered an error while generating this report - no need for email

Tags: jasperserver

I have JasperReports Server Community 6.3.0 and some reports scheduled to be executed and delivered by email. When a report fails, the server sends 2 emails:
1) "JasperReports Server encountered an error while generating this report.  Please contact your administrator." - only this text in the body. The title is the same as the title of the report email.
2) A "failure notification" as set up in the tab "Notifications" of my scheduler and this one contains my own failure message.

I would like to turn off the email 1) and keep only email 2). Where and how I can do this? I could not find where to do this.

Thanks and regards
Pawel

Comment: It is better to find over source code (or just at folder with resources) this text and then customize/replace it

Comment: Hmmm... this will anyway send the message 1). I would like not to send that message at all in my case. I only need one email to be sent, the one I set up myself as a notification (number 2) above) that is sent to specific recipients only (the report owners) and not to all regular recipients of the report. I do not need to inform all users that a report failed. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you happen to find any information regarding not sending the email if there was an error?

Comment: No :( I keep receiving those 2 emails, unfortunately.